# Prove the identity $\int_{2a-1}^{2a} f(x)dx = 2 \int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$

Tags: integration

I'm struggling with an integral. I'm allowed to use Maple, but even that doesn't help.

I have the following functions:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^{4/3}}\ln(1+\ln x)$$
and 
$$g(x)=f(2x-1)-f(2x)$$
And I wish to show: 
$$\int_{2a-1}^{2a} f(x)dx = 2 \int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$$
I already tried integration by parts for the LHS, but that went wrong. Can somebody help me please?

best wishes, Joe

Comment: You could show your attempts in detail, and also elaborate on where this integral came from as it seems unnecessary complicated

Comment: i think no solution in the known elementary functions is possible

Comment: The question is divided in two. I also have $$g(x)=f(2x-1) -f(2x)$$ which leads to the question can you show that: $$ 2 \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx\int_{2a-1}^{2a} f(x)dx$$ But I thought , lets start with the easy part :-)

Comment: I meant: $$2 \int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx =\int_{2a-1}^{2a} f(x)dx$$

Comment: Please edit your post with the *actual* problem statement, which makes much more sense

Comment: I adjusted the question

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond, I'm absolutely certain that to prove this equality, you do not need to evaluate the integrals. You just need to be clever and show through some substitution that one integral is equal to another

Comment: @YuriyS, I think you are absolutely right, but in a way I think I'm blind (after 4 hours watching it)

Comment: I have taken the liberty of updating the title so it reflects the actual question

Comment: No problem, I think it reflects more the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the integral on the left exists. Then it can be formally written as:

$$\int_{2a-1}^{2a} f(x)dx=F(2a)-F(2a-1)$$

Where:

$$F'(x)=f(x)$$

Define:

$$G'(x)=g(x)$$

Now differentiate:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (F(2x)-F(2x-1))=2 f(2x)-2 f(2x-1)=-2 g(x)$$

So we can write, up to a constant:

$$G(x)=\frac{1}{2} (F(2x-1)-F(2x))$$

You see where I'm going with this?

Further hint: you only need the explicit form for $f(x)$ to deal the limit for $G(x)$ at $x \to \infty$.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was too much focussed on the integral, but this makes it all clear.

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond, that's good. Next time if the task seems impossible, ask yourself if you are really supposed to do it

Comment: Perhaps I can add a second part: Can we show that: $$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^{k-1}f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}g(k)$$ I feel it has the same solution, but cannot see it. I think the solution is somewhere in the 2N. But where?

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond, maybe, but how is that relevant? If this is another question, you should make another post

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.